# Copying Formula From Above

Tags: excel, vba

We have a macro working via a button in Excel 2013 to insert a new row with formula from above.  the Problem is when it runs and i say for example copy from row 10 the formula in the new row 11 all still read back to row 10 not 11?

```
Sub Loop_InsertRowsandFormulas()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Risk Input Sheet")
Dim vRows As Long
Dim lastCol As Long
Dim firstRow As Long

firstRow = InputBox("Enter Row To Start Insert From.")
vRows = InputBox("Enter Number Of Rows Required")

If firstRow = 0 Or vRows = 0 Then Exit Sub
Debug.Print firstRow
IngA = ws.Cells(5, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For myLoop = 1 To vRows
    ws.Range("A" & (firstRow + myLoop)).EntireRow.Insert
    ws.Range("A" & (firstRow + myLoop) & ":BB" & (firstRow + myLoop)).Formula = ws.Range("A" & firstRow & ":BB" & firstRow).Formula
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: How can i make it just copy the formula and not the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do a `Copy/Paste`.  For example, if **A1** contains:

```
=B1+C1
```

running:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Range("A2").Formula = Range("A1").Formula
End Sub
```

will leave **A2** with `=B1+C1` as well.

If you want the copied formula to "adjust" then:

```
Sub ytrewq()
    Range("A1").Copy Range("A2")
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

Rather than:

```
ws.Range("A" & (firstRow + myLoop) & ":BB" & (firstRow + myLoop)).Formula = ws.Range("A" & firstRow & ":BB" & firstRow).Formula
```

use something like:

```
ws.Range("A" & firstRow & ":BB" & firstRow).Copy ws.Range("A" & (firstRow + myLoop) & ":BB" & (firstRow + myLoop))
```

Comment: Sorry but VBA is new to me.  Can you explain??

Comment: @Chris  See my **EDIT#1**

Answer (score 1):

Cannot take any praise for this.  Thanks Dave.

```
Sub Loop_InsertRowsandFormulas()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Risk Input Sheet")
Dim vRows As Long
Dim lastCol As Long
Dim firstRow As Long

firstRow = InputBox("Enter Row To Start Insert From.")
vRows = InputBox("Enter Number Of Rows Required")

If firstRow = 0 Or vRows = 0 Then Exit Sub
Debug.Print firstRow
IngA = ws.Cells(5, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For Myloop = 1 To vRows
    ws.Range("A" & (firstRow + Myloop)).EntireRow.Insert
    ws.Range("N" & (firstRow) & ":AW" & (firstRow + Myloop)).FillDown
Next

End Sub
```