# How to insert multiple rows with the formulas and format from above (pushing lower rows with their format down)?

Tags: excel, vba

I am new with VBA and I don't seem to get this right.
I have this:

[image]

where

```
      F         G        H
3   =1       =F3+1    =G3+F3
4   =F3+1    =F4+1    =G4+F4
5   =F4+1    =F5+1    =G5+F5
6   =F5+1    =F6+1    =G6+F6
7   =F6+1    =F7+1    =G7+F7
8   =F7+1    =F8+1    =G8+F8
9
```

and I want to use VBA:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    With Worksheets("Tabelle1")
        
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        
        Dim Limit As Double
        Limit = 15
        
        Dim nextRow As Long
        nextRow = 9
        
        Dim Index As Long

            For Index = nextRow To Limit Step 1
                Rows(nextRow).Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormulaFromLeftOrAbove
                Range("F" & (Index - 1) & ":H" & (Index - 1)).Copy Range("F" & Index & ":H" & Index)
            Next
        
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        
    End With

End Sub
```

to get the following:

```
      F         G        H
3    =1       =F3+1    =G3+F3
4    =F3+1    =F4+1    =G4+F4
5    =F4+1    =F5+1    =G5+F5
6    =F5+1    =F6+1    =G6+F6
7    =F6+1    =F7+1    =G7+F7
8    =F7+1    =F8+1    =G8+F8
9    =F8+1    =F9+1    =G9+F9
10   =F9+1    =F10+1   =G10+F10
11   =F10+1   =F11+1   =G11+F11
12   =F11+1   =F12+1   =G12+F12
13   =F12+1   =F13+1   =G13+F13
14   =F13+1   =F14+1   =G14+F14
15   =F14+1   =F15+1   =G15+F15
16
```

but I get this:

[image]

```
      F         G        H
3   =1       =F3+1    =G3+F3
4   =F3+1    =F4+1    =G4+F4
5   =F4+1    =F5+1    =G5+F5
6   =F5+1    =F6+1    =G6+F6
7   =F6+1    =F7+1    =G7+F7
8   =F7+1    =F8+1    =G8+F8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
```

---

I have used these as reference:

- https://powerspreadsheets.com/excel-vba-insert-row/#Example-3-Excel-VBA-Insert-Row-with-Same-Format-as-Row-Above
- [Copying Formula From Above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37965078/copying-formula-from-above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally I got what I wanted with a different approach. I used Excel's option to record macros, recorded three different methods and then wrote the following:

```
Sub Makro4()

    With Worksheets("Tabelle1")
        Worksheets("Tabelle1").Activate
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

            Dim Limit As Double
            Limit = 15
            Dim nextRow As Long
            nextRow = 9

            Rows((nextRow) & ":" & (nextRow)).Select

            For Index = 1 To (Limit - nextRow + 3) Step 1
                Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            Next
    
            Range("F8:H8").Select
            Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("F8:H" & (Limit + 2)), Type:=xlFillDefault
            Range("A1").Select

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

End Sub
```

result:

[image]

Comment: I'm glad this works, but you should always try to avoid Selects. Just a tip :-)

Comment: The general problem is that is dramatically slows down your macro. It works, but you should avoid it as a rule of thumb. https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/how-to-avoid-the-select-method/ contains a guide on how it can be easily avoided. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in a much simpler fashion, as Excel/VBA has the built in function `Range.AutoFill` available. You can read the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofill).

```
Sub FillDown()
    Dim ws as worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1")

    With ws
       Set src = ws.Range("F4:H4")
       Set target = ws.Range("F4:H15")
    end with

    src.AutoFill Destination:=target 


End Sub
```

Comment: thanx! this option inserts the numbers but it doesn't insert rows. thus, the black line gets lost.

Comment: So you wish to keep the formatting? Sorry, I could not see that specified in the question..

Comment: yeah... I kept the text very short, but put in in the title :P